# API Authentication Using Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, authentication

I am a beginner in backend development, and I want to learn API authentication using spring boot and REST API. I have tried with JWT but am not able to understand the implementation. Which one should I start with? Can you provide some Resources?

Comment: IMHO If you are new to backend development, There are a lot of things you need to learn before implementation. I dont want you to be afraid but first understand the concept then apply it

Comment: I wrote some custom code to learn new Authentication Authorization mechanism in spring. I have some useful information. https://github.com/grkn/auth_server. If you insist to begin before learning, then check other codes that apply some logic

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're not yet comfortable with Spring Boot, focus on
   understanding its core concepts and how it simplifies Java
   development.
2. Before implementing JWT, understanding the basics of web security,
   authentication vs. authorization, and how they apply in web
   applications is crucial.
3. Once you're comfortable with the basics above, start exploring JWT.
   Understand what JWT is, how it works, and why it's used for
   authentication.

Some Resources to start with:

- https://spring.io/guides
- https://www.baeldung.com/
- https://jwt.io/introduction
- Spring Boot in Action, by Andrew Glover

and there are a lot of tutorials on YouTube, you can also start with them

hope this helps, remember learning backend development is a journey consistency and practice are key.